# Appengine downloading remote server data to local datastore fail?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am following this site:

http://mbrochh.tumblr.com/post/6937702727/importing-google-app-engine-datastore-into-your-local

which tells me to download my datastore data by:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=s~appname --url=http://appname.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv
```

which has been successfully executed. Now I want to upload it to my local datastore via:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --filename=data.csv --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ your_app_folder
```

and I am getting:

```
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: app "dev~oyoroiapp" cannot access app "oyoroiapp"'s data
```

Appengine has removed the `--default_parition` parameter in recent api updates. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` into the folder containing the local `data.csv` file, then:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --application=dev~appname  --filename=data.csv --num_threads=5
```

I think you are missing the `application=dev~appname` flag, and perhaps in the wrong directory.